# App Crashes when Bitmap Option inSampleSize = 1

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image

I am testing the app on my phone (size 720x1280). The app runs fine when I use the sample size of 2. When I tried to use the sample size of 1 the app crashes in the line where I draw the image (code mentioned below). Please point me where my code need correction.

```
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null);
```

### Code

```
    public  Bitmap getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assets = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream buffer = null;
        try {
            buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        options.inPurgeable = true;  

        if (tabletSize) {
            Log.i("DragDrop", "am tablet");   
        } else {
            Log.i("DragDrop", "am phone");  
            options.inSampleSize = 1; 
        }


        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, options);
        Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, (int) dWidth, (int) dHeight, true);
        temp.recycle();
        temp=null; 
        return finalImage;   

    }
```

### LogCat

```
07-07 12:28:14.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7256): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-748
07-07 12:28:14.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@416ec9f0
07-07 12:28:14.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7256): at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1026)
07-07 12:28:14.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7256): at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1065)
07-07 12:28:14.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7256): at com.example.funandlearn.DragDrop$MyBringBackSurface.run(DragDrop.java:640)
07-07 12:28:14.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7256): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

For your reference Line # 640 has the code

```
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgoundImage, 0, 0  , null);
```

Comment: it says you have recycled bitmap and you are using the same.

Comment: What your android version?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. Look at this link for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this

```
    Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer, null, options);
    Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, (int) dWidth, (int) dHeight, true);
    temp.recycle();
    temp=null;
```

Your logcat says

```
    Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap
```

You should recycle bitmap when not in use.

Quoting from the docs

**On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, using recycle() is recommended.**

You should use `recycle()` only when you are sure that the bitmap is no longer being used. If you call recycle() and later attempt to draw the bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap".

**Manage Memory on Android 3.0 and Higher**

Android 3.0 (API Level 11) introduces the **BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap** field. **If this option is set, decode methods that take the Options object will attempt to reuse an existing bitmap when loading content**. No need to use `recycle`.

Also check this

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html